# Proving An Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have been revising basic compound angles and I am struggling to understand the following question from the examples I have previously studied on such topic.

A first step, or point of direction/suggestion would be brilliant. Thank You.

The instantaneous current ($i$) and the instantaneous voltage ($v$) in a pure resistance AC circuit is given by;
\begin{equation}
i=i_{max} \sin(\omega t)
\end{equation}
 and
\begin{equation}
 v=v_{max} \sin(\omega t).
\end{equation}
Since power is computed
\begin{equation}
P=iv=i^2 R
\end{equation}
Show that an equation for instantaneous power is
\begin{equation}
P=i_{max}^2 R \left(\frac{1−\cos(2\omega t)}{2}\right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

You might want what is often called the Power Reducing Identity $\sin^2 x = \dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this given for the power equation or applicable for (i) and (v)?